# Why is data not rendering on home page using useEffect hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { Box, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { POKEMON_API_URL,IMAGE_API_URL} from './configs';

function Pokedex() {
    const [pokemonData,setPokemonData]=useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(POKEMON_API_URL + "?limit=100").then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                const { results } = res.data;
                let newPokemonData = [];
                results.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
                    index++
                    let PokemonObject = {
                        id: index,
                        url:IMAGE_API_URL+index+".png",
                        name:pokemon.name,
                    }
                    newPokemonData.push(PokemonObject);
                });
                  
                setPokemonData(newPokemonData);
            }
        })
    },[])


    return (
        <Box>
          {pokemonData ? pokemonData.map((pokemon)=>(
               <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
          )) : <CircularProgress style={{marginTop:100}} /> } 
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Pokedex;
```

Comment: Are you getting a valid network response back? What is the value of `res` in the `.then` block? Have you verified that state is updated?

Comment: please print console.log(res)

Answer (score 0):

check this way if works, i used `async await` which is more cleaner approach to avoid non debuggable `.then()` call hell, also used dependency in `useEffect`, hoping it wont be recursive call,

```
import { Box, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { POKEMON_API_URL,IMAGE_API_URL} from './configs';

function Pokedex() {
    const [pokemonData,setPokemonData]=useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        const res = call();
        if (res) {
            const { results } = res.data;
            let newPokemonData = [];
            results.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
                index++
                let PokemonObject = {
                    id: index,
                    url:IMAGE_API_URL+index+".png",
                    name:pokemon.name,
                }
                newPokemonData.push(PokemonObject);
            });
                
            setPokemonData(newPokemonData);
        }

    },[pokemonData])

    const call = async () => {
        const data = await axios.get(POKEMON_API_URL + "?limit=100");
        const res = data.json();
        console.log(res); // check if there is any data
        return res;
    }


    return (
        <Box>
          {pokemonData ? pokemonData.map((pokemon)=>(
               <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
          )) : <CircularProgress style={{marginTop:100}} /> } 
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Pokedex;
```